# Can't see the cursor's movement programmatically

Tags: c#, console-application, mouse-cursor

OK there, after really doing some research and trying a lot of examples-

[Moving mouse cursor programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647236/moving-mouse-cursor-programmatically)

[How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c)

[Getting mouse position in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316681/getting-mouse-position-in-c-sharp)

[Control the mouse cursor using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082770/control-the-mouse-cursor-using-c-sharp)

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoveMousePointer.aspx

and becomes frustrated I'm asking you guys for help.

I'm trying to move the cursor, programmatically (in console application, c#).

**-->** As I read the altered location it seems fine - but I can't actually see the difference. The cursor's image staying the same place...

**I want to actually see the cursor at it's altered location**

Thanks

Edit 2: Thank you all guys for helping, currently I'm just keep working without seeing the cursor moving anywhere... so its hard to get any feedback about it's locations (just guessing).

Comment: Are you actually trying to move the mouse cursor (which doesn't seem to make sense for a console application) or are you trying to manipulate the text cursor inside the console?

Comment: [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx) ?

Comment: @JustinNiessner I'm want to create a program that make the mouse cursor to move and click in different windows and buttons in my Win-OS.

Comment: @Sinatr Already been at that page. Sorry, its not seem to be helpful

Comment: From your previous comment it is clear what you need to *set mouse position programmatically* (not *cursor*, not *move*, this will lead you to very other topics). In winforms you do it [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) way. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8185916/1997232) and perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14063542/1997232)

Comment: @Sinatr Every method is working. But - I cannot actually see the cursor, only moving symptoms (like rising tool tip somewhere)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't see any problem, here is a test code, it works for me (win7_64):

```
class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MousePoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetCursorPos(out MousePoint lpMousePoint);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKey key;
        MousePoint point;
        while ((key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key) != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            GetCursorPos(out point);
            if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
                point.X -= 10;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                point.X += 10;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                point.Y -= 10;
            if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
                point.Y += 10;
            SetCursorPos(point.X, point.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Credits goes to @Keith [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121314/1997232).

---

It does this

[image]

Comment: sorry it does making the mouse moving - but the cursor actually can't be seen

Comment: Did you try to press cursor keys? My mouse pointer is moving pretty well.. all around other windows. Or what do you mean as `cursor can't be seen`? You may have to add screenshots to your question, as you can see peoples (me?) having problem to understand what you want.

Comment: Well.. it does working and its very nice one - but still, I'm just seeing tool tips rising up because some ghost cursor